# DOMDocument insert <h1> tag before </body> tag

Tags: html, dom, domdocument

How can I insert an `<h1>` tag right before closing `</body>` tag?

```
$html = '
    <html>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>Blalala</span>
    </body>
    </html>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
//$body= $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
//Somehow insert h1 tag before </body> tag
echo $doc->savehtml($html);
```

Comment: h1 is for example. I will need to append img tag with some unique URL, created by function and POST request. As it is unique, I have to append it dynamically...

Comment: See [DOMDocument::createElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. As in a docs DOMNode::appendChild — Adds new child at the end of the children

```
<?php
$html = '
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>Blalala</span>
    </body>
    </html>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$hNode = $dom->createElement("h1");
$body->appendChild($hNode);
echo $dom->savehtml();
```